# How to prevent TinyMCE 5 from removing \r\n

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, line-breaks, resource-cleanup

I want TinyMCE 5.0 to keep linebreaks in original content, same as it is working in Wordpress now.

Example:

> This is first line\r\nThis is second line.

How it works:

> This is first line This is second line.

What I expect:

> This is first line
>
> This is second line.

I added this configuration to Tinymce.init:

```
remove_linebreaks: false,
force_br_newlines: false,
force_p_newlines: false,
forced_root_block: '',
keep_styles: false,
fix_list_elements:true,
entity_encoding:"raw",
extended_valid_elements : '*[*]',
cleanup: false,
cleanup_on_startup: false,
trim_span_elements: false,
verify_html : false,
end_container_on_empty_block:true,
remove_trailing_brs: false,
```

Plugins:
Plugins:

```
plugins: [
  'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
  'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen, textpattern',
  'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
],
```

But it still removes my newlines. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE is an HTML editor - your newline characters are not HTML so TinyMCE's HTML validation code is removing them.

You would need to convert that to valid HTML before you try to load it into TinyMCE if you want to retain the effect of a new line.  You could turn that character combo into a `<br>` or `<p>...</p>` to get the effect of a line break.

Comment: Yes, I not found a better solution. So I used function wpautop on the Wordpress side to warp the text into `<p>`...`</p>`.